# Best option for classes for porting onto GPU via Intel OpenCL SDK in a Visual Studio Solution

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencl, intel

I have a C++ solution running on Visual Studio. I have been trying to port my code onto the GPU with OpenCL using Intel OpenCL SDK for parallel processing. Now, I have some classes in my solution. Now, can someone could give a better choice out of these two following options:

1. Convert the class into a struct and pass to the kernel.
2. Can I use any extension for SYCL along my visual studio 2015.
3. Does the new Visual Studio 2017 RC update include the SYCL in it.
4. Also, I have function that have been declared within the class which are being used in my source files.

Would someone be able to help me with regards to the same implementation on the Kernel side.
Thanks in advance for any help with respect to this question.
If anyone needs any additional information wrt any question, I would be more than happy to help.

Comment: hi Harrison, isn't there a feature in the Intel SDK plugin that translates automatically C++ into OpenCL? https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/539288

Comment: @ L30nardo, thank you for your reply, however, at the time when I started with this i was not able to find such an option. However, I am completely beyond the stage I was, if you could have given this input a few months earlier then certainly I would have considered the option you are suggesting. I have already ported my code, however, if you can suggest a tool for OpenCL optimizations or help with work group size for local and global I would really appreciate it.